# Looking for Phonegap/Cordova plugin to play HLS video on android?

Tags: android, html5-video, cordova-plugins, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

Could any one point me to a working cordova plugin that plays hls/m3u8 streams on android ? I tried using JW Player and html5 video tag and both didn't work!Thanks in advance.

```
<video id="myVideoTag" width="320" height="250" onerror="playbackFailed(event)" poster="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/video-play-icon-26.gif" autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://www.nacentapps.com/m3u8/index.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: JW Player supports HLS streams on Android (both natively with the JW Player Android SDK and for mobile web). A premium license is required.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to add jw player to cordova project ?I tried to add it to index.html and player didn't show up!

Comment: JW Player isn't supported in webviews, but you can use the Android SDK to build the player into your native apps: https://developer.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/

Comment: Well i am working on cordova app for android not pure native app so there is no way to use it on cordova?